# Why isn't Android Studio Profiler showing activity on AsyncTask threads

Tags: java, android-asynctask, profiler, java-threads

I have two AsyncTask threads that each move files from one folder to another however this activity is not showing on the Android Studio Profiler

Honestly completely lost as every now and then it will show activity for 200ms but only once and on one of the threads

In MainActivity:

```
    new AsyncThread().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,  true);
    new AsyncThread().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,  false);
```

AsyncTask:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Boolean... Upper) {
    while(startPoint <= (endPoint)){
       ...

        try {
            if (sourceFile.exists()) {
                try{
                    sourceFile.renameTo(targetLocation);
                    publishProgress();
                    startPoint++;
                } catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            } else {
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("failed: ", "nullPointer");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("failed: ", "exception e");
        }
        try {Thread.currentThread().sleep((int)(1000));
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
    try{
        MainActivity.semaphore.acquire();
        MainActivity.noOfFilesTransfered++;
        MainActivity.semaphore.release();
    } catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Threads that are `sleep()`-ing don't show activity on the profiler, because they are not running. Your threads spend most of their time sleeping.

It is not immediately clear what that 200ms of activity represents, but you can rest assured that your profiler is correct, and that 200ms represents a thread that is actively running.